# Nested <a> tag click region in <li> tag not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

The `<a>` tag click region works for `<li>` tags 1,3, and 4 but the nested `<a>` tag in `<li>` 2 and 5 have no clickable region. Here's the Codepen link (the `<a>` tag has been defined in the CSS): http://cdpn.io/tAiFw

Also, is it possible to keep the hover state when the user clicks on the button (e.g. when the user clicks the plus and moves their mouse away, the 'X' stays active and when the user clicks again, the 'X' returns to the '+')

Comment: Always put the relevant code and markup **in the question**, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index on the `ul` below `<div class="position">` is set to -10 which effectively sets it behind the background, making it unclickable.

Comment: Yeah, I fixed it by placing the z-index on the <li> tags and then changing the z-index when the <li> elements slide out

Comment: Excellent, don't forget to choose an answer with the checkmark!

Comment: Just a tip I like to use, I add an 'active' class to elements with state actions. So when you have clicked on your expand button. Add the active class to the ul. That way you can use that to style with. Cuts down on javascript markup too!

Comment: The 'active' property doesn't seem to work - I've put it on the trigger element (e.g. trigger:active) and set the same properties as in the trigger:hover state. The button still returns to the '+' when the user moves the mouse away after clicking.

Comment: I'm talking about an active class. So you have your ul, the style for when it is active is `ul.active`, and for when it is inactive it is `ul`. And if it is being hovered over you can do `ul:hover`. And you can override that if it is active and being hovered with `ul.active:hover`

Comment: The pseudoclass :active is different then what I am proposing.

Comment: Ah ok - what if I wanted to apply this approach to the button (e.g. trigger class)? The button is not part of an list structuring.

Comment: This is valid for any DOM element. You can add an active class to anything. Even the body and html elements (Which can be very very useful). Just make sure when selecting the element you are using descriptive selectors. For example, provide an id to the button you would like to use. Use javascript/jquery to add/remove the class. Then in css select the active button with `#myButton.active`. If you are just selecting by for example the anchor tag `a`. You will apply this styling to any anchor tag that currently has the 'active' class.

Comment: $(".trigger").click(function () {
    $(".trigger").removeClass("trigger");
  $(this).addClass("trigger-active");        
});
This works when the trigger-active css is the same as the hover state. The challenge is returning back to the normal state when the user clicks again to return to the '+' - it stays the same as trigger-active. I'm thinking of an IF statement but not sure how to write it in jquery

Comment: For example, if the button is selected, change the value to 1 and add the new class. If the button is clicked and equal to 1, return the value to 0 and add the original class.

Comment: Fixed the issue using button.classList.toggle('trigger-active');

Answer (score 1):

Change `z-index` for `<ul>`:

```
ul{z-index: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `z-index` of `ul` to zero:

```
ul {
    z-index: 0;
    ...
}
```

and add `position: fixed` to `.trigger`

```
.trigger {
    position:fixed;
    ...
}
```